# Infinite dynamic Iteration over Collection in Java

Tags: java, list, loops, dynamic, collections

Imagine I have a collection, in which someone dynamically adds elements, so it gets 0,1,2... etc and never finishes.
From another program I want to access that collection, but I never want to get the same element I have already taken.

For example, if collection is 10 elements long from the beginning, other guy iterates over it and reads all 10 elements, at this point it's done, but as collection may get new element to it (after some time), I want that other guy to take that new element, and keeping an eye, when something will be added to the collection.
If other guy will just iterate over collection once, and then check if length got larger and in case of true, will iterate again, that other guy will copy the old values again... I want it to be dynamic.. that other guy gets new element as soon as new element is added to the collection.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Use an event-like mechanism. Make your app send a notification/event to the client whenever a new element gets added to the collection, so that the client knows he has to pull all the newer elements.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a queue: the producer pushes elements into the queue, the consumer removes them (from the start). Have a look at `Queue` and its implementations, e.g. `LinkedList` (or maybe `BlockingQueue` etc.)